# Linux Scripting -- best way to extract data based on patterns from verbose logs

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, awk, sed

Sometimes, it's useful to have verbose logs for eyeballing, but painful to extract data to read. For example

```
10:16:43.002 EVENT [ID = 1013] Order fill with quantity 115 and price 74.42 for owner 234
```

I want to extract 10:16:43.002, 1013, 115, 74.42 from the above log line into a CSV file. So I can analyze them together.

Is there a generic solution? By generic I mean I can put in some verbose English string patterns. I would prefer not counting characters or field numbers.

The pattern would ideally be like

```
TT EVENT [ID = AA] Order fill with quantity BB and price CC for owner DD
```

I want to extract TT, AA, BB, CC, DD

Comment: What is the pattern here?

Comment: You can use `sed` and some regular expressions and save them into different variables, then just concatenate them together. It seems like the data is the same format for every row so it'll work. https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: There are some excellent tools for the job -- see `libgrok`, and [based on it, as a complete stack for doing bulk extraction of structured data from logs w/ indexing and analysis via ElasticSearch] Logstash. As tool recommendation requests are explicitly off-topic, though, I'm not sure I can answer on that basis within the site's scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*) EVENT \[ID = (.*)\] Order fill with quantity (.*) and price (.*) for owner (.*)/\1,\2,\3,\4/' file
10:16:43.002,1013,115,74.42
```

or with GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ gawk '{ print gensub(/(.*) EVENT \[ID = (.*)\] Order fill with quantity (.*) and price (.*) for owner (.*)/,"\\1,\\2,\\3,\\4",1) }' file
10:16:43.002,1013,115,74.42
```

or also with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS = "," }
match($0,/(.*) EVENT \[ID = (.*)\] Order fill with quantity (.*) and price (.*) for owner (.*)/,a) {
    for (i=1;i in a;i++) {
        printf "%s%s", (i>1 ? OFS : ""), a[i]
    }
    print ""
}

$ gawk -f tst.awk file
10:16:43.002,1013,115,74.42,234
```

That last one is best if you want to do more than just print the values since they're saved in an array between finding and printing them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9:\.]+).* \[ID = ([0-9]+).*quantity ([0-9]+).*price ([0-9\.]+).*owner ([0-9\.]+)/\1;\2;\3;\4;\5/' file
```

Output :

```
10:16:43.002;1013;115;74.42;234
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but words without digits can be removed and replaced with;

```
sed 's/[^[:digit:]]* /,/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the most convenient way of defining such patterns is via the `scanf` format string:

```
$ cat log|scan "%s EVENT [ID = %d] Order fill with quantity %d and price %f for owner %s"
10:16:43.002,1013,115,74.42,234
```

The `scan` utility has a simple implementation in Tcl:

**scan**:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set fmt [lindex $argv 0]
append fmt %n
while { [gets stdin line] >= 0 } {
    set fields [scan $line $fmt]
    if { [lindex $fields end] == [string length $line] } {
        puts [join [lrange $fields 0 end-1] ,]
    }
}
```